# AdonisJS - Gerar código do banco de dados já criado

Tags: mysql, node.js

Estou com uma dúvida. Gostaria de saber se é possível.
Tenho um servidor Mysql já rodando um modelo meu, com tabelas já criadas e seus devidos campos. Tem alguma forma de conectar um projeto Node, Adonis e aproveitar minhas tabelas do Mysql para gerar o código fonte?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu não conheço o adonisjs, mas o `node` e `express` sim e com ele é possível sim, só codificar o model no node de acordo com as regras das tabelas do seu banco de dados e então poderá consumir toda a informação disponível. Pode ser usado os modulos nativos do `mysql` ou até mesmo o `sequelize` vai funcionar bem.

Edit: Dei uma pesquisada no `adonisjs` e pelo que li com ele também seria possível, posso estar sendo leviano, mas se ele for tudo o que li vai consumir bem os dados também.